# PDO fetchColumn() won't work after INSERT

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have `SQL` `insert` statement and after that i catching scope_identity and i need to pass this parameter into another function...

```
$sql = $db -> prepare("
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT data from ....

SELECT scope_identity()
")
$sql -> execute();
   echo  $row = $sql ->fetchcolumn();
```

And output is `nothing` but it works in SQL management studio.

Comment: What is the middle select? is it part of INSERT or a separate query? if so, why is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not INSERT but SELECT you are getting your data from. So make it consistent

```
$sql = $db -> prepare("
INSERT INTO ...");
$sql -> execute();

echo $db->query("SELECT scope_identity()")->fetchcolumn();
```

Comment: @Is it posible to keep everything in same statement

Comment: Any reason you want to keep in same statement?

Comment: Is no specific reason just trying to keep simple

Comment: I can assure you that running each query in a separate call IS the way to keep things as simple as possible

Comment: Output is still null